# How to alter redshift column encoding in place?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-redshift

Is there a way to add/alter table column encoding on the original table without creating a new table and select all content from old table into new table ?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

**Update**: as pointed out by @gelin: since Oct 2020, altering column encodings in place is now supported:  `ALTER TABLE tablename ALTER COLUMN columnname ENCODE newencode`. More info [here](https://aws.amazon.com/about-aws/whats-new/2020/10/amazon-redshift-supports-modifying-column-comprression-encodings-to-optimize-storage-utilization-query-performance/).

<s>No, this is not supported.</s>

From the [documentation](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/t_Compressing_data_on_disk.html), the options that you have:

- apply a compression type, or encoding, to the columns in a table manually when you create the table
- use the COPY command to analyze and apply compression automatically (on an empty table)
- specify the encoding for a column when it is added to a table using the ALTER TABLE command

From the same documentation,

> You cannot change the compression encoding for a column after the table is created.

Comment: Now (from Oct 2020) it's allowed as `ALTER TABLE tablename ALTER COLUMN columnname ENCODE newencode`.

The announcement: https://aws.amazon.com/ru/about-aws/whats-new/2020/10/amazon-redshift-supports-modifying-column-comprression-encodings-to-optimize-storage-utilization-query-performance/

Comment: Amazingly great news on this announcement. So painful to backfill a TB scale table with years of daily loads, now should be much easier vs. workarounds.

Answer (score 8):

Ketan is correct.  AWS does provide a utility, https://github.com/awslabs/amazon-redshift-utils/tree/master/src/ColumnEncodingUtility, that can take care of it for you though.

Comment: This utility essentially does what original question described. It creates a new table, then does "insert into <new_table> select * from <old_table>", then renames the tables.

Answer (score 4):

Yes - this is now a supported option as of 20th Oct 2020, see AWS docs :

```
ALTER TABLE table_name 
{
| ALTER COLUMN column_name ENCODE new_encode_type
```

https://aws.amazon.com/about-aws/whats-new/2020/10/amazon-redshift-supports-modifying-column-comprression-encodings-to-optimize-storage-utilization-query-performance/

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/r_ALTER_TABLE.html

Answer (score 2):

You don' really have to create a parallel table with the new encoding. You could alter the existing table by adding a new column with the desired compression, update the new column with the values from the old column and finally, drop the old column.

Comment: I found that this method is very simple to implement, also setting the new column to the old column is pretty fast. Wonder what the caveat is though.